# How to search for a memory address

Tags: java, memory

I want to look at what is stored at this specific memory addresses on my machine: 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 - 0xffffff.

I have no clue how to do it.

What I want is a simple piece of code that lets me type something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class searchByMemoryAddress
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      boolean[128] a = findData(0xffffff);             //Simple piece of code like this
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
   }
}
```

Surely there must be something like this in java?

Comment: Problem 1: Modern operating system implement memory protection so you can't access arbitrary memory. Problem 2: Java does not allow you to address memory in any way directly. Problem 3: Even if Java did, Java runs a virtual machine; you would only be able to see memory in that virtual machine (presumably). Only viable solution: Use a different language and hope you don't trigger something in the OS. JNA and JNI are both available, and allow Java to link to and invoke native code. I would not classify this as "simple". Merely "possible".

Comment: Now, if you really wanted to monitor the Java Virtual Machine; [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/) has you covered!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you know of any other way to access a memory address of a computer directly? I'm interested in what is stored at specific locations of memory in my computer.

Comment: Buy an (older) computer with open firmware. Using forth commands you can access arbitrary regions of ram. Boot an (even older) operating system like DOS. Using any number of languages (or just DEBUG), you can access arbitrary regions of ram. Buy an (even older still) computer like an 8-bit computer, using `PEEK` in BASIC you can access arbitrary regions of RAM. Finally, write your own operating system. If you're the kernel, you can access arbitrary regions of RAM.